# wcf : what is the use/significance of xsd files generated when we add wcf service reference

Tags: wcf

Whats the use of xsd files generated for xml types, operation contracts and data contracts.
Isn't the information in wsdl file is sufficient to generate all required classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default WCF generated WSDL has reference to external xsd files to describe the types in the SOAP messages. This is a multifile WSDL as opposed to single file WSDL. You can use [WCF Extras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) library to generate single file WSDL if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on WSDL generator. WSDL always needs XSD description for message types, custom headers, faults and data types. These descriptions are needed on client side to built the proxy and to know what type of data do you need to send or receive from operation. It describes serialization of data types.

Some generators inject these XSD directly into WSDL but other create separate files and only include these external files in WSDL.